# setColor Java not working

Tags: java

I'm following a tutorial for a simple game engine and for some reason setColor does not work when I try to fill a rectangle. I just get a blank white screen. I've looked at the other similar posts but none of them seemed to help me out. Here is the code:

```
package com.binaryscythe.SA.main;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

/**
* @author 4nd3r
*
*/
public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3472639816592189040L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 1920, HEIGHT = WIDTH / 16 * 9;  
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = false;

    private Handler handler;

    public Game() {
        new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, "Senum's Adventure", this);
        handler = new Handler();
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        try {

        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 100000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frames = 0;
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1) {
                tick();
                delta--;
            }
            if (running)
                render();
            frames++;

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS: " + frames);
                frames = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    private void tick() {
        handler.tick();
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null) {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();

        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);  

        handler.render(g);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       new Game();
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't create a Window because Window doesn't take those four arguments! How does your program even run?

Comment: @ Jossie Calderon how do you know how many parameters does his window class takes?

Comment: presume Window and Handler classes are created by Komodo himself. To test his code, try using a `awt.Frame` and after preparing GUI, add the class Game(which extends Canvas) to that `awt.Frame`, then draw in `paint` method.

Comment: @rupinderjeet47 Im pretty sure its only about his running boolean as I mentioned in my answers, still being downvoted for some reason.

Comment: @eldo edited my answer for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by *eldo*,

> As far as I can see, you never set your `running` variable `true`. Your frame shows up but your game-loop never actually reach your `render` method. Try `running = true;` in your `start` method.

please check the `running` boolean variable. If this is the case, please mark his answer as accepted.

Otherwise, you can try following code snippet too:
 By `paint` method and cast `Graphics` to `Graphics2D`

```
@Override
  public void paint (Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    g2.setColor(Color.blue);
    g2.fillRect(50, 50, 300, 300);  

  }
```

Comment: @eldo and rupinderjeet47 thank you guys so much! That was it! Stupid tutorial never explained that smh.

Comment: Wow, thank this stupid community to downvote the right answer.